# Example Gaussian Primes

Tags: gaussian-integers

I want to ask somethink. Is it possible to a number, prime in **Z[i]** but not prime in **Z**? If yes what's the example? If no, how to prove it?

Comment: Unless the number is not in $\Bbb{Z}$, it's not possible: a factorisation in $\mathbf{Z}$ is also a factorisation in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Well, $1+i$ is a Gaussian prime, for example.

Comment: @lulu yes I know 1+i is Gaussian prime but not prime in Z since it's not element of Z. But is there any element of Z which prime in Z[i] but not prime in Z?

Comment: Well, no.  If $n=ab$ is a composite integer then $n=ab$ is a composite Gaussian integer.

Comment: Hello @Rob Arthan , I still don't get it why it's not possible, a factorization in Z is also a factorization in Z[i]. Can you explain it more specific or with example? Thank you.

Comment: Worth remarking, the only integers which are units in $\mathbb Z[i]$ are $\pm 1$.  Hence teh factroing $n=a\times b$ with $a,b>1$, is again a factoring into non-unit Gaussian integers.

Comment: If $n$ is composite in $\Bbb{Z}$, so $n = xy$, where $x, y \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $x$ and $y$ are not units in $\Bbb{Z}$, then $n$ is composite in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ too because $x$ and $y$ are not units in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ either (as you can see by considering norms).

Comment: Thank you guys, I understand all of your explanation.